# Facebook Sharing for SPA without server side support (hosted on a CDN)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, single-page-application

> I have a static website, an **SPA hosted on a CDN** -  basically a
>   singe index.html whose content area is updated based on the hash in
>   the url. I need to find a way for FB sharer to show title and
>   description of the currently loaded main content in the SPA

Facebook sharing, in simple words,  scrapes a page to find og meta tags and caches them. This info is then displayed when we try sharing the url/page.

```
<meta property="og:url"         content="http://www.siteurl.com" /> 
<meta property="og:title"       content="My Site" /> 
<meta property="og:image"       content="Site-img.jpg" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="Description" />
```

I tried setting the meta tags using javascript but eventually realized when scraping, Javascript is not executed, therefore modifying the meta tags using javascript is of no use.
The other solution would have been setting the og tags from the backend before the page loads but being hosted on the CDN there is no server side support to do that.

Thoughts on how I could work this out?

Comment: If you want to share different objects, you should have different URLs for those objects as well.

Comment: I do have different urls for each page.
http://www.siteurl.com/index.html#page1
http://www.siteurl.com/index.html#page2

Comment: Those differ only in the hash part, which is only relevant client-side.

Comment: @CBroe Not sure I understand how I can have different URL's.  Mine is a SPA; so primarily one page whose content keeps getting updated based on hash.
1. How could i get different URL's?
2. For my SPA if i do managed to use different url's inplace of hash tags, how could it solve the issue? for each url the og tags will be the same (since its still a single html page) or am i missing something?

Comment: You have to set it up server-side in a way that delivers different OG meta data for different URLs. Whether or not the presentation looks different client-side (“one page”) is another matter.

Comment: That is the crux of the problem. I am hosted on a CDN and don't have a server-side :)

Comment: Of course you “have” a server-side, otherwise you would have no website … If there’s no other options available, then you can still manually create individual HTML documents carrying the OG meta data for each pseudo “page” of your SPA … and redirect human visitors that come there via a link shared on FB back to the appropriate section of the SPA using JavaScript …